# Which url structure should I choose for seo?

Tags: seo, url

I am preparing a site that offers a variety of information in a particular area, i've searched here and on many seo sites, but I've always gotten different answers.

I'm undecided about the url.

For example, let's say the subject of my site is SEO, and urls can be like this.

```
www.site.com/seo/tools/link-checker
```

In fact, I favor the site structure to be understandable.

Now i have 3 options in front of me, which one is better in terms of seo and user

```
1-www.site.com/post-name/

2-www.site.com/single-category/post/name/

3-www.site.com/category-name/sub-category/post-name/
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's mostly personal preference? I myself like the first one the most, because then I will always have the possibility to restructure my site and move things from one category to another without the page being hurt.

Answer (score 0):

- If the actual category names are themselves relevant/targeted kewords, go with #3. Use-case: Tutorials and stuff alike.
- If the actual name of the post is itself relevant/targeted as well, go with #2. Use case: Online commerce etc.
- If you'd rather have all the focus on the item itself, go with #1. Use-case: Publishing/blogging.

I suppose your use-case might fit #3.

The SEO benefit of any approach is mostly unknown, but if you assume that it's non-negligible I think this makes the most sense: put things there only if people actually search for them, not your internal/technical names.